# Visual Studi Code could not find the task ever

Tags: linux, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, archlinux, manjaro

I'm using manjaro linux and Visual Studio Code can't debug any code ever, in any language, always giving me the "Could not find the task 'xxx'" error. The xxx part differs for every language, every program I try and every configuration I choose. What do I do?

launch.json

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "cpp - Build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "cpp build active file",
            "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb"
        }
    ]
}
```

tasks.json

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "C/C++: clang build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/clang",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "/usr/bin"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": "build"
        },
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "C/C++: clang++ build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/clang++",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "/usr/bin"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": "build"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: The problem could depend on the programming language. Each programming language has its own debugger and different JSON files for configuration. Could you please edit the post with launch.json and tasks.json files.

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu Linux 20.04 LTS what got preLaunchTask working for me, was using both a local tasks.json and launch.json (as opposed to global launch config in: ~/.config/Code/User/settings.json)

So a basic local folder structure (pre-build) might be:

```
.vscode/launch.json
.vscode/tasks.json
src/index.js
package.json
```

My launch.json contains:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "preLaunchTask-build",
            "program": "${file}",
            "preLaunchTask": "build",
            "skipFiles": [
                "<node_internals>/**", "node_modules",
              ]
        },
    ]
}
```

My tasks.json contains:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "echo hello yes working!",
            "problemMatcher": [],
            "label": "build"
        },
        {
            "type": "typescript",
            "tsconfig": "tsconfig.json",
            "problemMatcher": ["$tsc"],
            "group": "build",
            "label": "tsc: build"
        },
    ]
}
```

Usage: whilst within the index.js just hit F5 with a breakpoint set.

I also included a "tsc: build" version to see another build config example (swap index.ts for index.js is this example)